Link will not open in a new tab
When I click the link button it opens the page in the same tab. I have the target attribute = "_blank" but it doesn't work.
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>AMZNindex.html</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-
EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

<h1>AMZN/index.html</h1>


<button onclick="document.location='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN/'" target="_blank">stock price</button>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-
    MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>


You're confusing buttons and links.  If this <button> is meant to be a link then make it a <a> with href and target attributes.

This question is similar to: How to open link in a new tab in HTML?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

target="_blank" should be used on an anchor element (<a></a>).
<a href='https://google.com' target='_blank'>Stock price</a>


If you really need a button, use window.open which has a second parameter for opening new tabs:
<button onclick="window.open('https://google.com', '_blank');">Stock price</button>


The target="_blank" attribute should be placed inside the  tag, not the button tag. To open a link in a new tab when clicking a button, you can use JavaScript to achieve this.
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>AMZNindex.html</title>
        <link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-
EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>AMZN/index.html</h1>

        <button
            onclick="window.open('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN/', '_blank')"
        >
            stock price
        </button>

        <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-
    MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
    </body>
</html>

The onclick attribute of the button now uses window.open('URL', '_blank') to open the link in a new tab.

This should ensure that the link opens in a new tab when the button is clicked.


    window.open('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN/','_blank')

How to add target="_blank" to JavaScript window.location?

We can not use target="_blank" as an button's attribute. It will not work.
To use this attribute we have to apply it in <a> tag
That will show up like:
<a href="link_you_want_to_add" target="_blank"> <button>Text</button> </a>

